# Concat first item of array to first itiem of second array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

how can I concat more rationally first item of array to first of second array and so on? Basically automate console.log here is the code:

```
$("button#search").on("click", function(){
var inputVal = $("input#text").val();
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + inputVal +"&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json&callback=?", function(json) {
    var itemName = $.each(json[1], function(i, val){    
    })
    var itemDescription = $.each(json[2], function(i, val){ 
    })
    var itemLink = $.each(json[3], function(i, val){
    })
    console.log(itemName[0] + " " + itemDescription[0] + " " + itemLink[0]);
    console.log(itemName[1] + " " + itemDescription[1] + " " + itemLink[1]);
    console.log(itemName[2] + " " + itemDescription[2] + " " + itemLink[2]);
    console.log(itemName[3] + " " + itemDescription[3] + " " + itemLink[3]);
    console.log(itemName[4] + " " + itemDescription[4] + " " + itemLink[4]);
    })//EOF getJSON
});//EOF button click
```

Comment: If all 3 arrays have same number of elements then you can do a for loop for the length and use the iterator `i` to access array value by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {
  console.log(itemName[i] + " " + itemDescription[i] + " " + itemLink[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Good to see you again Hodges :)

Answer (score 1):

If arrays have the same length, you could use `map`

```
var result = $.map(json[1], function(i, val){
    var row = val + " " + json[2][i] + " " + json[3][i];
    console.log(row);
    return row;
}
```

Also you can use that `result` later, e.g.

```
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: Good solution, but I cannot upvote until you address the "Basically automate console.log" statement from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Using es6 you can do the following:

(in your getJson callback):

```
function (json) {
    const [value, optionsJ, descriptionsJ, linksJ] = json;
    let whatIwant = [];

    // choose one to loop through since you know they will all be the same length:
    optionsJ.forEach(function (option, index) {
        whatIwant.push({option: option, description: descriptionJ[index], link: linksJ[index]});
    });

    // use whatIwant here**
}
```

Your new `whatIwant` array will then contain objects for each set.